# Is there anyway to embed a Google Sheet that allows dropdown boxes?

Tags: google-sheets, iframe, dropdown, embed

After spending too much time building this spreadsheet I was rudely brought aware that you can't iframe with dropdowns

Is there any possible way to allow an embedded spreadsheet to use dropdown boxes?

Comment: Have you thought of using Google Forms that will send data to this sheet. Also google form has solid regex validations and also supports apps script.

Comment: Hmmmm, using Forms.... I hadnt thought of that ---

here's more of the sitch - 

Its a spreadsheet of contacts listed by title and department. I made a drop down so you could select which dept and it'd sort/filter to your selection. But that dropdown is disabled in iframes --- I could explore Forms option but I wonder if there are any script options here (haven't dabbled in scripts so I'm clueless here)

Comment: But why share sheet in frame though, google sheets itself an wrapper. Protect those 2 columns, editing rights to only you. Disable sharing by editors/viewers. Disable downloading. These options are available in front end, no script required.

Comment: But even sharing in its native embed disables the dropdown boxes .... I might not be following what you mean

Comment: So you have a sheet with col A as titles and col B as dept which has dropdown. Use 'Protect Range' option to reserve editing to only you in it's options. In sharing settings there is check mark which allows editors to add more editors, disable that. Then You share the sheet with intended recipients as it is, by using native share button.